# Efficient Approach For File Large File Download

Tags: java, download, large-files

I am working on a Java based web application.This application consumes  REST API for its data via a custom made rest client which is a sub component of the application.Now I am stuck in a situation where I have to write code for downloading  a large file.The rest client calls the api , obtains data stream from the Response and writes the file at a particular location at the server.

Should I read the file and write it to the output stream? Or is there any more efficient way to achieve this functionality?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am using the same approach of reading the large file and writing it to the output stream.The rest client sub component reads the file data from the rest api and writes it at a temporary location on the server.
After that I read that file and write it to the output stream.